# mySQL datetime comparing syntax error

Tags: mysql, datetime, locking, mysql-error-1064, between

I am making a booking system for my mother and I have some problems locking already booked times.

Here is the code:

```
SELECT event_start
FROM annagretasjoberg
WHEREevent_start BETWEEN 2011-8-1 1:30:00 AND 2011-8-1 2:0:00
```

Here is the reply from the mySQL server:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1:30:00 and 2011-8-1 2:0:00' at line 1

Answer (score 3):

Date datatype **must be enclosed in quotes**:

```
select event_start from annagretasjoberg where event_start 
between '2011-8-1 1:30:00' and '2011-8-1 2:0:00'
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to put your example dates in single quotes in order for SQL to parse it correctly:

```
SELECT event_start
FROM annagretasjoberg
WHERE event_start BETWEEN event_start between '2011-8-1 1:30:00' and '2011-8-1 2:0:00'
```

Answer (score 2):

Put quotes around your dates:

```
SELECT event_start
FROM annagretasjoberg
WHEREevent_start BETWEEN '2011-8-1 1:30:00' AND '2011-8-1 2:0:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the date values between single quotes, e.g.

```
select event_start from annagretasjoberg where event_start between '2011-8-1 1:30:00' and '2011-8-1 2:0:00'
```

I also would encourage you to use parametrized queries.